# Getting "a" in place of a white space in Assembly language

Tags: assembly, character, ascii

I am writing a code, which capitalizes small letters. The program works like a charm but where it comes a white space in String, the program instead of a White space, inserts "a". I am trying to insert a white space using its ascii code which is 32. Here is the chunk of code messing up the program.

```
WhiteSpace2:
sb $t1,New($t0)
addi $t0,$t0,1
j Small
```

- $t1 contains the ascii value of White space
- $t0 is offset for the byte in String.
- New is the String label

This program is written in assembly language.Somebody tell me why I am getting "a" instead of a Whitespace.

Regards

Comment: Is this tagged correctly? I'm not aware of any such opcodes on x86. I certainly didn't think there was any three operand version of add.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple the addi, takes the second and 3 operand and the sum is written to the first op

Comment: @coolbartek I understand how three operand opcodes work, but I'm looking at an Intel manual and I don't see an addi opcode. When I looked at the question it was tagged x86.

Comment: @DirkHolsopple i didn't see the tag of x86 when i wrote the comment, sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

I do not really see what you are trying to accomplish in the code.

To make a program that capitalizes, you have to see if the char is between asci 'a' and 'z', if it is, subtract a constant value (32 if i remember). For any other char, just copy it.